# ReactJS and JSX - can I have uncontrolled checkbox?

Tags: reactjs

In React I can have uncontrolled text inputs by using `defaultValue` property. However, there is no such property for checkboxes (there is only `checked`, which makes it controlled). I have a huge form with lots of checkboxes, but user can't change them! Probably I can use two-way data binding mixin, but docs suggest not to use them, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `defaultChecked`

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values